# Using two view controllers, second one won't display views

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

For some reason I'm having trouble displaying a view from a secondary view controller in my application.
My main view controller calls another view controller that's responsible for loading a pdf view.

The code in MainViewController looks like this:

```
- (int)openPDF
{
    [self loadSettingsWithDefaults];
    RDPDFViewController *m_pdf;
    if( m_pdf == nil )
    {
        m_pdf = [[RDPDFViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RDPDFViewController"bundle:nil];
    }
    int result = [m_pdf PDFOpen:@"/Users/steve/test.pdf" withPassword:@""];
    if(result == 1)
    {
        m_pdf.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:m_pdf animated:YES];
    }
    return result;
}
```

This code is located in the second view.  This is the method referred to above in MainViewController.

```
- (int)PDFOpen:(NSString *)path withPassword:(NSString *)pwd {
    [self PDFClose];
    PDF_ERR err = 0;
    m_doc = [[PDFDoc alloc] init]; err = [m_doc open:path :pwd]; switch( err )
    {
        case err_ok: break;
        case err_password: return 2;
            break; default: return 0;
    }
    CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    //GEAR
    if (![self isPortrait] && rect.size.width < rect.size.height) { float height = rect.size.height;
        rect.size.height = rect.size.width;
        rect.size.width = height;
    }
    //END
    if(SYS_VERSION>=7.0) {
        m_view = [[PDFView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)]; }
    else
    {
        m_view = [[PDFView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height-20-44)];
    }
    [m_view vOpen :m_doc :(id<PDFViewDelegate>)self];
    pagecount = [m_doc pageCount];
    [self.view addSubview:m_view];
    return 1; }
```

When the code executes, I know the view object is being created as I can see debug output coming from it in the console.  However it will not display the new view in the iPhone simulator.

Feel free to provide feedback--just remember this is my first StackOverflow post!  I'll be happy to provide more info as needed.

Comment: Have you created your first view controller inside of a UINavigationController?

Comment: The first view controller is created on application startup and works fine.  All my other screens work. But to answer your question, a quick search of 'navigationcontroller' (non-case sensitive) doesn't show up anywhere in reference to the first view controller.

Comment: When dealing with multiple views that are being pushed through the stack (rather than displayed modally) you need to embed them in a UINavigationController. Clearly you're calling it (`[self.navigationController pushViewController:m_pdf animated:YES];`) but if you haven't actually connected your VCs to the navigation controller, nothing will happen.

Comment: ah ok. That makes sense.  I appreciate your input! I'll try that out and see what happens.  I'm new to objC and am learning as I go on this project...looks like I may need to find a good book...

Comment: so after I do that, would I need to do anything else to make sure that control is handed back to the first view controller OK, or is that entirely dependent on how the second view controller is written?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking? If you're talking about the delegate method, then so long as you set the delegate to the appropriate controller, it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

My main view controller was set to be the root view controller for my application.  I had to set the navigation controller to be the root view controller, and then add the other view controllers after that.

After that I told navController to pop to the root view controller.

```
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```